# API Gateway cloudformation method before path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm writing a cloudformation for api gateway, I'm getting this ordering issue with the resource path and method.

[image: path ordering issue]

What I want is to have the path (/hi) a level above and the method GET to be below it.

This is the snipet of cloudformation script that I wrote to generate this (excluded permission, lambda, policies etc...), also I'm aware of some of the tools for doing this, but they're not approved for our situation.

```
MyAPI:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties: 
      Name: "TestAPI"
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types: 
          - REGIONAL

ApiGatewayResourceHi:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
    Properties: 
      ParentId:
        Fn::GetAtt: ["MyAPI", "RootResourceId"]
      PathPart: "hi"
      RestApiId:
        Ref: "MyAPI"

HiMethodGet:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref MyAPI
      ResourceId: !GetAtt
        - MyAPI
        - RootResourceId
      HttpMethod: GET
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration: 
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
        Type: "AWS_PROXY"
        Uri: !Join ["", ["arn:", !Ref "AWS::Partition", ":apigateway:", !Ref "AWS::Region", ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/", !GetAtt ["HiLambdaFunction", "Arn"], "/invocations"]]
    DependsOn:
      - ApiGatewayResourceHi

ApiGatewayDeployment1: 
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment"
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: 
        Ref: "MyAPI"
      StageName: "dev"
    DependsOn:
      - HiMethodGet
```

Everything seem to work fine, I can invoke and hit the endpoint and it response fine.  It's just this ordering issue, as some of our other api gateway are structure with path before method (although they're created manually).  Maybe this is the right way and it's fine?  If someone spot a problem in my script or suggestion between the two layouts, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing what you want the API to look like in the console graphically as the "GET" being below the "/hi". What the console is showing is that the "GET" method is attached to the root path and that the root path has a resource named "hi" that has no method. I assume you want the "hi" resource to have a GET method, which will display as you described, and also seems like a logical api design.

The reason it was created as it was is because you've set the resource for the method as RootResourceId.

What you want to do instead is set the resource as your "Hi" method.

Comment: That didn't quite work, it gave error if I set the resource to "Hi" method, but it helps pin point down the problem.  What I had to do was to Ref the resource that I have declared for the method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working the way I wanted, with @TheClassic suggestion it didn't work but it helped pin point the problem, this is the changes that I had to make for it to work.

```
ApiGatewayResourceHi:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
    Properties: 
      ParentId:
        Fn::GetAtt: ["MyAPI", "RootResourceId"]
      PathPart: "hi"
      RestApiId:
        Ref: "MyAPI"

HiMethodGet:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref MyAPI
      ResourceId: !Ref ApiGatewayResourceHi

......
```